# aircrack , Please specify a dictionary (option -w)?

Tags: aircrack-ng

Following [this tutorial](https://www.wikitechy.com/technology/hack-wifi-passwords-ubuntu/) I am trying to determine the wifi password of my home using **aircrack** tool.

After all the steps mentionened in tutor, i get wep-01.cap to crack; when i run :

```
aircrack-ng wep-01.cap
```

i get this:

```
#  BSSID              ESSID                     Encryption

1  00:24:17:BD:A0:AF  6B4B43                    WPA (0 handshake)
2  00:E0:20:1B:20:D6  6B4B43_Ext                None (0.0.0.0)
3  FC:AB:90:B7:78:B6  HUAWEI Y9 Prime 2019      No data - WEP or WPA
4  1C:15:1F:DF:9C:C3  HUAWEI Mate 10 lite       No data - WEP or WPA
5  0C:96:BF:B4:C7:35  Ooredoo-E5151-c735        None (192.168.8.1)
```

and then a question :

```
Index number of target network ?
```

so i choose 1 and i get this response :

```
 Opening wep-01.cap
 Please specify a dictionary (option -w).


 Quitting aircrack-ng...
```

what is wrong , i expected to get the password ?

## Update

thank you for your response , i have downloaded **password.lst** example from [here](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=faq#where_can_i_find_good_wordlists) , re-run the command i get now this message :

```
No valid WPA handshakes found..
```

what that means ? do i need to try other lists ?

Answer (score 2):

You chose a network with WPA encryption, not WEP. `aircrack-ng` is not supposed to crack a WPA encryption without a provided dictionary.

Read the [manual](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aircrack-ng#error_message_please_specify_a_dictionary_option_-w):

> **Error message "Please specify a dictionary (option -w)"**
>
> This means you have misspelt the file name of the dictionary or it is not in the current directory. If the dictionary is located in another directory, you must provide the full path to the dictionary.
>   [...]
>
> *Remember, WPA/WPA2 can only be cracked via a dictionary technique.*

<sup>(*emphasis mine*)</sup>

And in the [WPA usage example](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aircrack-ng#wpa):

> **WPA**
>
> Now onto cracking WPA/WPA2 passphrases. Aircrack-ng can crack either types.
>
> `aircrack-ng -w password.lst *.cap`
>   Where:
>
> - -w password.lst is the name of the password file. Remember to specify the full path if the file is not located in the same directory.
> - *.cap is name of group of files containing the captured packets. Notice in this case that we used the wildcard * to include multiple files.

Comment: where i can find password.lst ?

Comment: Start [here](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=faq#where_can_i_find_good_wordlists) or google.

Answer (score 0):

The "tutorial" you've used is for cracking WEP encryption. I think it's fair to say that no-one uses this anymore because it's so easy to crack. Even your own network runs WPA, so the "tutorial" is of little use to you.

I would suggest you go and read up on the differences, for example on the [aircrack website](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa).

---

In response to your question edit where you have switched from WEP to WPA but now get the error message, "No valid WPA handshakes found.", I repeat my earlier advice. I would suggest you go and read how to use the tool, for example on the [aircrack website](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa#aircrack-ng_says_no_valid_wpa_handshakes_found).

Stop trying to use a tool without reading up on how to use it.